# Why does checking an empty string against string.hexdigits() return valid?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex

I have two functions, one that cleans the input text, and one that tests if the cleantext is hexadecimal. When passing the cleaner function a string of all spaces, it strips the spaces, leaving a null string.

What I don't get is why string.hexdigits() doesn't barf on this null string, and let's it pass through as valid hex.

```
def testHex(ciphertext):
    cleancipher = cleanHex(ciphertext)
    if all(h in string.hexdigits for h in cleancipher):
        print('String is valid hex.')
    else:
        print('String is not valid hex.')

def cleanHex(ciphertext):
    return(ciphertext.replace(' ', '').replace('0x', '').replace(':', '').replace('\\x', '').strip())
```

Comment: `why string.hexdigits() doesn't barf` - Actually it does... `string.hexdigits` is a string, you can't call it and get an error for trying.

Comment: People are brutal with downvotes on SO even though this isn't in search. Closing question now.  **Edit:** Didn't realize I couldn't delete with an answer on board. Just keep downvoting me I guess. Thanks community.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm expecting it to barf for not being a hexdigit, not for not being a string. The submitted answer cleared it up for me.

Comment: What you just said makes *no* sense.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Great thanks for being so helpful.

Comment: I tried to be, you're just ignoring me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102759/discussion-between-cremefraiche-and-stefan-pochmann).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testHex` outputs `String is valid hex.` for empty strings because `all` returns `True` for empty iterables

It is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

> all(iterable)
>
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the
>   iterable is empty).

Comment: Thank you, I was so busy parsing the string.hexdigits() documentation I didn't think to check all(). I will accept when timer expires in 10min.